# Is Structuremap singleton thread safe?

Tags: c#, singleton, thread-safety, structuremap

Currently I have the following class:

```
    public class PluginManager
{
    private static bool s_initialized;
    private static object s_lock = new object();

    public static void Initialize() {
        if (!s_initialized) {
            lock (s_lock) {
                if (!s_initialized) {
                    // initialize

                    s_initialized = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing here is that Initialize() should only be executed once whilst the application is running. I thought that I would refactor this into a singleton class since this would be more thread safe?:

```
    public sealed class PluginService
{
    static PluginService() { }
    private static PluginService _instance = new PluginService();
    public static PluginService Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    private bool s_initialized;

    public void Initialize() {
        if (!s_initialized)
        {
            // initialize

            s_initialized = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Question one, is it still necessary to have the lock here (I have removed it) since we will only ever be working on the same instance?

Finally, I want to use DI and structure map to initialize my servcices so I have refactored as below:

```
    public interface IPluginService {
    void Initialize();
}

public class NewPluginService : IPluginService
{
    private bool s_initialized;
    public void Initialize() {
        if (!s_initialized) {
            // initialize

            s_initialized = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And in my registry:

```
            ForRequestedType<IPluginService>()
            .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<NewPluginService>().AsSingletons();
```

This works as expected (singleton returning true in the following code):

```
            var instance1 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IPluginService>();           
        var instance2 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IPluginService>();

        bool singleton = (instance1 == instance2);
```

So my next question, is the structure map solution as thread safe as the singleton class (second example). The only downside is that this would still allow NewPluginService to be instantiated directly (if not using structure map).

Many thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 3):

I would make several recommendations:

- the boolean flag should be `volatile`
- make your singleton instance `readonly`
- the initialization is not thread safe, regardless of the fact that you have only one instance... so it should be synchronized

  ```
  public sealded class PluginService
  {

  static PluginService() { }

  //make the instance readonly
  private static readonly PluginService _instance = new PluginService();
  public static PluginService Instance { get { return _instance; } }

  // make the flag volatile
  private static volatile bool s_initialized = false;
  private static object s_lock = new object();


  // you still need to synchronize when you're initializing
  public void Initialize() {
      lock(s_lock)
      {
          if (!s_initialized)
          {
              // initialize

                  s_initialized = true;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

There is no contention on the structured map, so its thread safety doesn't seem compromised...

The singleton class you had was not thread safe. The main thing to remember is that a single instance does not ensure a single thread can only access it. If there are multiple threads that have a reference to the instance, then there is contention on the instance and the data it's holding. If there is contention then you should ensure thread safety (synchronize at the very minimum).

Comment: @Lirik - great help thanks. Which of these suggestions would apply when using structuremap to get the instance?

Comment: @Ben are you initializing the instance every time you get it from the structured map? Are you accessing the structured map from multiple threads in order to get instances?

Comment: @Lirik - this was my point really - StructureMap has a method AsSingletons for marking an instance as a singleton. What I wanted to know is whether this would offer the same thread safety that I had with a hard coded singleton (in addition to your suggestions).

Comment: @Ben where did you get the StrucureMap from?

Comment: @Lirik - StructureMap is a DI / IoC tool. I'm using it to inject all my dependencies hence why I wanted to program against IPluginService.

Comment: @Ben I doubt that the StructureMap will be making Singleton instances in a thread safe manner... I don't have access to the StructuredMap to verify that and I don't know how it was implemented. So are you calling AsSingletons from multiple threads?

Comment: @Lirik - according to http://structuremap.github.com/structuremap/Scoping.htm the instance will be shared accross multiple requests / threads. However I intend to research this fully and until then will not use structuremap for this and will implement your suggestions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ben the documentation does mention that you can create a ThreadLocal instance, but if you're new to threading then I would recommend that you try a simpler solution. Good luck :)!